# Simulation an interpolation ( adding zeros) in VHDL

Tags: fpga, filter, vhdl

Given an input vector :

```
data_in:     in std_logic_vector( 5 downto 0);
```

I am going to shift the `data_in` and create an array of data:

```
for i in 1 to 9 loop
  shift_data_in(i) <=  shift_data_in(i - 1);                           
end loop;
```

`shift_data_in` is an array of vectors:

```
type data_array is array (integer range 0 to 9)  of std_logic_vector ( 5 downto 0);     
signal shift_data_in: data_array     := (others => (others => '0'));
```

The next step is inserting `0`s between original `data_in`:

```
if Int_enb= '1' then
  shift_data_in(0)    <=  data_in;
else -
  shift_data_in(0) <=  (others => '0');
end if;
```

I send `shift_data_in` as output ( check this implementation):

```
data_out    <=  shift_data_in(9);
```

A test bench file will give me a value for `Int_enb`:

```
if(4 = counter) then      
   counter <= 0;
   Int_enb <= '1';
else
  counter <= counter + 1;
  Int_enb <= '0';
end if;
```

I don't see any syntax error. The code can be compiled, but as output it gives me 0.
Could someone help to find Where I have mistaken?

**EDIT 1**

The main file( design)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;

entity main is
GENERIC
        (
          bits:           integer := 12;                                
          taps:             integer := 69           );
    Port
        (
        Clk:                                    in  STD_LOGIC;  
        Rst:                      in  std_logic;
        data_in:                   in std_logic_vector( (bits - 1) downto 0);
    FirEn:                    in std_logic;                                       
    Int_enb :                    in std_logic :='0';                                
        
        data_out:       out std_logic_vector( (bits - 1) downto 0)
        );
  end main;
  architecture Behavioral of main is

    type data_array is array (integer range 0 to (taps - 1))  of std_logic_vector ( ( bits-1 ) downto 0);   
    signal shift_data_in    : data_array     := (others => (others => '0'));

begin
    main_process : process(Clk)
        begin       
        if rising_edge(Clk)  then
          if Rst = '1' then                   
         data_out <= (others => '0');
      elsif FirEn = '1' then
        for N in 1 to (taps - 1) loop
           shift_data_in(N) <=  shift_data_in(N - 1);                           
        end loop;           
        if Int_enb  = '1' then
           shift_data_in(0)    <=  data_in;
        else 
            shift_data_in(0)    <=  (others => '0');
        end if;                
              data_out    <=    shift_data_in(taps - 1);
             
                end if;
            end if; 

          end process main_process;
   

     
  end Behavioral;
```

and the test bench:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use STD.textio.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity main_tb is
end main_tb;

architecture Behavioral of main_tb is

 constant bits:             integer := 12;                          
 constant taps:             integer := 69;                        
 constant M:                integer := 4;
       
 signal Clk       : std_logic := '0';
 signal Rst       : std_logic := '0';
 signal FirEn     : std_logic := '1';
 signal Int_enb   : std_logic := '0';

 signal data_in    : std_logic_vector( (bits - 1) downto 0) := (others => '0');
 signal data_out   : std_logic_vector(  (bits  -1) downto 0);


 constant Clk_period : time := 20 ns;    -- Clock period definitions
 signal   counter  : integer range 0 to M - 1 := 0;  


    COMPONENT main
      PORT(
          Clk:                                      in  STD_LOGIC;  
          Rst:                      in  std_logic;                   
          data_in:                  in std_logic_vector( (bits - 1) downto 0);

          FirEn:                    in std_logic;                                         -- enables multiply add chain
          Int_enb:                  in std_logic :='1';                                   -- signals new FIR Input
                    
          data_out:    out std_logic_vector( (bits - 1) downto 0)
                    
          );
   END COMPONENT;


begin
UUT : main PORT MAP(
--uut : entity work.main port map (        
          Clk => Clk,
          Rst => Rst,
          data_in    => data_in,
          FirEn                   => FirEn,
          Int_enb                   => Int_enb,
          data_out      => data_out
        );

        
           Clk_process :process               --
           begin
            Clk <= '0';
            wait for Clk_period/2;
            Clk <= '1';
            wait for Clk_period/2;
        end process;

        
        generate_clk_enable_process : process (Clk)
                begin
                   if (rising_edge(Clk)) then
                       if((M -1) = counter) then      
                           counter <= 0;
                           Int_enb    <= '1';
                        else
                           counter <= counter + 1;
                           Int_enb    <= '0';
                        end if;    
                   end if; 
                end process generate_clk_enable_process;
                
                
process                
begin  
 Rst  <= '1';
   FirEn <= '0';
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  Rst <= '0';
  FirEn <= '1';
  data_in <= "000101000100";
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  data_in <= "010101010101";
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  data_in <= "001001010001";
  wait until rising_edge(clk) ;
  data_in <= "000100110010";
  wait until rising_edge(clk) ;
  data_in <= "000100110010";
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  data_in <= "001001010001";
  wait until rising_edge(clk) ;
  data_in <= "000000000000";
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  data_in <= "110110101111";
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  data_in <= "111011001110";
  wait until rising_edge(clk); 
  data_in <= "111011001110" ;
  wait;
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

**EDIT 2**

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Can I use `integer`- vector as input vector? Does it make sense in a simulation a filter?

[In the test bench I would send a `std_logic_vector`, but convert first to `integer`. In the design file I would work with `integer` type of data. I believe then I don't need think about an extension of vector in addition step, for example.]

Comment: Show us the complete module, along with the testbench you use to drive the simulation. Otherwise, there's no way we can guess what your problem might be.

Comment: @DaveTweed  I have added

Comment: Which part of "did you run the simulator long enough" did you not understand?

Comment: @DaveTweed I got what you have meant. :)

Comment: In the Vivado built-in simulator, use the "Run For..." command and give it a value of at least 2 us. In the Wave window, make sure you zoom out far enough to see all of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting zero at the output is that you're only feeding zeros in.

Your sampling logic only accepts a new `data_in` value every five clock cycles, or every 100 ns. But for some reason, you're feeding data values at 10 ns intervals, and even more oddly, *every fifth value is zero*. So, your shift register only ever sees zero when it samples the data.

Comment: I have done changes in the test bench...it is still 0 in output

Comment: have i an error in the main file or in the test bench?

Comment: The testbench looks the same as before to me. But the error is definitely in the testbench, since it controls both the sampling interval and the data input, and it is doing so inconsistently.

Comment: Even if I remove the process `generate_clk_enable_process :` and set ` Int_enb`  as 1, I will still get 0

Comment: Hmm, it's working for me (ghdl + gtkwave). Are you running your simulation long enough? With 69 taps, it takes almost 1.5 us for the first result to appear.

Comment: I used the same files ( design and test bench) I added here. I got the output 0

Comment: What simulator are you using? Can you show us the output you're getting?

Comment: I am working with Vivado.

Comment: How did you compute 1.5 us? "With 69 taps, it takes almost 1.5 us for the first result to appear."

Comment: I didn't compute it. At first, I just ran the simulation for a few hundred ns. Then I realized that I didn't remember the length of your delay line, and after I checked, I just increased the run time to 10 us. But the computation would be 20 ns clock period * 69 taps = at least 1380 ns.

Comment: Even If I increase time, I will not get a correct output :(...Does it mean I have an error in the main file?

Comment: What do you consider to be the correct output? Your testbench does not define it.

Comment: I implement a shifter and a process of upsamplling. The input data should be shifted and 0s should be added between two inputs. Example:If I send 0001, I will get 1000, right?

Comment: No, not from what I can see.

Comment: Are you hoping to send in the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, ... and get out 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ?

Comment: If I shift an integer data, I will get the value itself, right?